# Confidence interval calculation in R (dplyr) with weights

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, data-wrangling, weighted

I have the following problem: I'm trying to calculate 95% CI range on categorical data with weights (lower and upper bound). I have the "response" variable which is either 0 or 1, and I have 2 factors (old vs. new, and 14 different color). Weighting per participant has been collected. Here's my dataset:

```r
dd <- data.frame(
  weight = c(0.0037, 0.0016, 0.0347, 0.3421, 0.1047, 0.0065, 0.0153, 0.2856, 0.0032, 0.0321, 0.0321, 0.0321, 0.0321, 0.0321),
  factor1 = factor(c("New", "Old", "New", "New", "New", "Old", "New", "Old", "New", "Old", "Old", "New", "Old", "Old")),
  factor2 = factor(c("Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Orange", "Brown", "Blue", "Black", "White", "Purple", "Gray", "Pink", "Navy", "Tan", "Fuscia")),
  question = factor(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14")),
  response = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)
)
```

I want to produce bar charts with weighted percentages for each question, for two factors, that looks like this:

```r
question    factor1    factor2      Weighted_pct   Lower 95%CI      Upper 95%CI
Q1           New         Red        21.3%          21.1%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Red        20.4%          20.1%            21%
Q1           New         Red        22.6%          20.5%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Red        19.6%          20.7%            22.3%
Q1           New         Red        11.8%          20.9%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Red        18.3%          20.4%            22.3%
Q1           New         Red        27.4%          20.6%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Red        6.3%           11%              22.3%
Q1           New         Red        32.0%          20.3%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Red        7.7%           20.3%            22.3%
Q1           New         Red        9.3%           20.3%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Red        15.3%          20.3%            22.3%
Q1           New         Red        22.1%          20.3%            22.3%
Q1           Old         Yellow     3.3%           20.3%            22.3%
```

Numbers are arbitrary but I hope this makes sense. I can get it to work using just one factor, but as soon as I introduce the second one, my code collapses.

My current code:

`new_data <- complete_data %>%` 
    `dplyr::select(dplyr::Question, factor1, factor2, Response, weight) %>%` 
    `tidyr::gather(key = Question, value = Response, -weight, -factor1, -factor2) %>%` 
    `dplyr::group_by (Question, factor1, factor2) %>%` 
   `dplyr::summarise (Unweighted_N = n(),` 
                     `Unweighted_pct = sum(Question) / Unweighted_N,` 
                     `Effective_N = sum(weight),` 
                      `Weighted_pct = sum (Question*weight)/Effective_N,` 
                     `N_yes = round(Weighted_pct*Effective_N),` 
                     `Low_95CI = binom.test(N_yes, round(Effective_N), conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[1],` 
                     `Up_96CI = binom.test(N=yes, round(Effective_N), conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[2]) %>%` 
`dplyr::select (Question,`  
              `factor 1,` 
              `factor 2,` 
              `Weighted_pct,` 
              `Low_95CI,` 
              `Up_95CI)`

Comment: Please share the code you're using. Seems like you should have a `group_by(factor1)` that needs to be come `group_by(factor1, factor2)` and nothing else should change...

Comment: Thanks! I just edited to add my code above. It doesn't work when I simply group by factor 2 as well :(

Comment: I don't understand how you can do `sum(Question)`. Shouldn't it be `sum(Response)`? Also, your dataset example has only one row per question, how is it connected to your expected output, where there are multiple rows per group (e.g. rows 1 and 3 seems identical to me)